# Mostrar un mensaje de "alerta" y dirigirme a otra página al dar clic en aceptar

Tags: c#, aspx, visual-studio-2022

La situación es la siguiente
Tengo un formulario en el cual se crean cuentas de usuario, necesito que cada vez que se cree una cuenta, aparezca un mensaje indicando que se ha creado.

Cuando se crea correctamente, como he puesto que se dirija al formulario que tengo para iniciar sesión, no muestra el mensaje y se va inmediatamente al formulario de login
Y si dejo comentada la parte de Response.Redirect, muestra el mensaje y en el navegador indica que no se puede acceder a esa página.

Necesito que cuando la cuenta se cree correctamente muestre el mensaje y después se dirija al login.

Es para una aplicación Web en Visual Studio 2022, lenguaje C#, archivos ASPX

[image: Mensaje]
[image: Falla]

```
string script = @"<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Usuario Creado');
                        window.location.href='http://localhost:44352/CrearCuenta.aspx'</script>";
                        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "alert", script, false);

                        Response.Redirect("https://localhost:44352/Login.aspx");
```

Comment: Favor poner esa primera imagen del código como texto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que hacer que javascript redireccione, porque haciendolo desde ASP nunca te va a mostrar el mensaje.

```
string script = @"<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Usuario Creado'); window.location.href='https://localhost:44352/Login.aspx'</script>";

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "alert", script, false);
//Response.Redirect("https://localhost:44352/Login.aspx");
```

Comment: ¿Alguna sugerencia para hacerlo?

Comment: @Cecilia Probaste el código que te puse?